# Update table data in biq query in command line

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to update the Big query table which satisfy in condition . I tried in command line it through an error

```
bq update `project_d.data_set.table_name`set field1='1011' , field2='201' , field3='2001' where id='7001'
```

But i'm getting error in command prompt like

```
Too many positional args, still have [',', 'field2=201', ',', 'field3=2001', 'where', 'id', '=7001']
```

please assit me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

`bq update` updates the attributes of a table, such as its expiration time. If you want to run an `UPDATE` query, use `bq query`. Put the following contents (substituting your project, dataset, and table name) into a file called e.g. `query.sql`:

```
UPDATE `project_d.data_set.table_name`
SET
  field1 = '1011',
  field2 = '201',
  field3 = '2001'
WHERE id = '7001'
```

Now run `bq query` with that file as input:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < query.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using external sql file, you can just add `--use_legacy_sql=false`:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'update dataset.table SET id=id*100 where id>100'
```